# ClickHouse - аналоги подзапросов

Tags: sql, clickhouse, подзапрос

Каким образом я могу заменить конструкцию с подзапросом например на join (или что-то иное) в следующем примере

```
select x.id,
   x.date_requested,
   (select count(distinct x2.bo_id) from x as x2
    where x2.bo_id <> x.bo_id
        and x2.id < x.id
        and x2.date_requested between x.date_requested - interval 1 day and x.date_requested
    ) as bo_1d
from x
```

| id | date_req | b_id | bo_1d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 325 | 0 |
| 2 | 02.01.2021 | 112 | 1 |
| 3 | 03.01.2021 | 118 | 2 |
| 4 | 04.01.2021 | 201 | 3 |
| 5 | 05.01.2021 | 113 | 3 |
| 6 | 06.01.2021 | 100 | 3 |
| 7 | 07.01.2021 | 325 | 3 |
| 8 | 08.01.2021 | 325 | 2 |
| 9 | 09.01.2021 | 199 | 2 |
| 10 | 10.01.2021 | 190 | 2 |

Выше представлен пример исходной таблицы к которой необходимо написать запрос. Суть запроса в следующем: необходимо посчитать для каждой строки количество уникальных b.id не равных b.id в текущей строке а так же id которых меньше, за период between date_requested - interval 3 day and date_requested

Пример расчета для строки id = 5
берем все строки где date_req between date_req - interval 3 day and date_req

| id | date_req | b_id | bo_1d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 02.01.2021 | 112 | 1 |
| 3 | 03.01.2021 | 118 | 2 |
| 4 | 04.01.2021 | 201 | 3 |
| 5 | 05.01.2021 | 113 | 3 |

далее фильтруем b_id <> 113

| id | date_req | b_id | bo_1d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 02.01.2021 | 112 | 1 |
| 3 | 03.01.2021 | 118 | 2 |
| 4 | 04.01.2021 | 201 | 3 |

далее count(b_id) и как результат для строки с id=5 мы получаем результат bo_1d = 3

Представленный скрипт в шапке написан на mysql, данную логику необходимо перенести на clickhouse

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте отдельно исходные данные, отдельно результат. И поясните со ссылкой на значения, как именно получен результат для пары строк (скажем, для id = 5 и 8)ю

Comment: @Akina расписал расчет для строки с id=5 остальные по такому же принципу

Comment: Ага... смотрим, что написано. *Суть запроса в следующем: необходимо посчитать для каждой строки количество уникальных b.id не равных b.id в текущей строке а так же id которых меньше, за период between date_requested - interval 3 day and date_requested* Прелестно, переходим к пояснениям для строки id=5. И с удивлением читаем: *далее фильтруем **b_id** <> 113*. Пересматриваем постановку задачи. По-прежнему упоминания b_id не находим. И задаём очевидный вопрос: не, ну какого, ёпрст, хрена, а?

Comment: @Akina на мой взгляд все предельно понятно, не хотите понимать не пытайтесь. У вас есть все и запрос который выполняет задачу и описание и даже поэтапная визуализация происходящего.

Comment: Ну дело Ваше. Не у меня проблема, в конце концов. Удачи, ждите того, кто "захочет понять".

Comment: @Akina да, спасибо. Задача на только первый взгляд тривиальная, я все понимаю)

Answer (score 0):

Если считать приведённый в тексте вопроса запрос верным, то следующий запрос является его полным эквивалентом:

```sql
SELECT x1.id,
       x1.date_requested,
       COALESCE(count(distinct x2.bo_id), 0) bo_1d
FROM x AS x1
LEFT JOIN x as x2 ON x2.bo_id <> x1.bo_id
                 AND x2.id < x1.id
                 AND x2.date_requested BETWEEN x1.date_requested - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND x1.date_requested
GROUP BY x1.id,
         x1.date_requested
```

Comment: На сколько мне известно оператор JOIN должен иметь точное сопоставление ON x.id = x1.id иначе не работает

Comment: @Maksimilianius Вам неверно известно. В ON clause может быть абсолютно что угодно - хоть ещё один подзапрос,- лишь бы результат мог быть приведён к булеву типу.

Comment: ваш вариант не работает

Comment: я добавил больше объяснений к своему вопросу выше.

Comment: требуемый результат в поле bo_1d

Comment: Поправил требуемый результат, там была ошибка, все исправлено, поле bo_1d имеет правильные значения для условия interval необходимо указать 3 day

Comment: что значит отдельно дать результаты, выше я расписал максимально детально на примере id = 5